# inline form bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can i inline these two fields . suppose textarea is 8col and input field is 4col .
here is the fiddle : **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvduxud4/)**

i want to add label in right no to left .

```
   <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="" for="address">آدرس مکاتباتی:</label>
                <textarea class="" cols="63" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
                <label>
                    پلاک:
                </label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="پلاک" ng-model="Address.IdentifierLeft" name="pelak" valid-number required />

    </div>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for right to left support, no need to change direction of your code, just simply include [Bootstrap RTL](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl) into your page.
Your form should look like this:

```
<div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8"> 
                     <label class="" for="address">آدرس مکاتباتی:</label> 
                     <textarea class="" cols="63" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <label>پلاک: </label>
                     <input type="text" placeholder="پلاک" ng-model="Address.IdentifierLeft" name="pelak" valid-number required />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your labels after the textarea and input fields.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hu9bgd3e/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="" cols="63" rows="3"></textarea>
        <label class="" for="address">:آدرس مکاتباتی</label>
    </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="پلاک" ng-model="Address.IdentifierLeft" name="pelak" valid-number required />
    <label>
            پلاک:
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Pull out the results view in the fiddle a bit, and it'll be inline.